# Create MultiIndex Dataframe from Dictionary of Lists

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I would like to create an empty, MultiIndex DataFrame where the first level of columns contains the dictionary keys, with the second level of columns containing the values for each key.

Example:

```
dictionary = {"Col 1": ["foo", "bar"], "Col 2": ["one", "two"]}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can flatten the dictionary for each key and value , then use [`pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.from_arrays.html) , then [`swaplevel`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.swaplevel.html):

```
d = {i:k for k,v in dictionary.items() for i in v}
df = (pd.DataFrame(columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays((d.keys(),d.values())))
      .swaplevel(axis=1).rename_axis(columns=['first','second']))

#df.to_excel(...)
```

---

[image]

Comment: What about if the second level column names are the same? E.g. Col 1: "foo", "bar", Col 2: "foo", "bar". This works perfectly except I have some second level names that are getting lost as they repeat.